# Flutter mobile app works during testing and fails from the Google Play Store

Tags: flutter, dart, http

Original problem: My flutter app using the http package connects to a rest service to get the data needed. If I am connected via my modems wifi, the connection would fail (but not timeout) on the login attempt. The circular spinner would spin forever (tried for 15 minutes). If I connect using my router's wifi, or my mobile data, the connection is fine. The app logs in and runs correctly.
I created a web app to test and after trying a few things, I found port 443 was the problem. I changed the port on my rest service and the app and now 2 emulators and 2 physical devices all work perfectly during testing.

Then yesterday I published the app update to the Play Store and the App Store. I'm still waiting on the app store to approve, but testing from TestFlight worked perfectly on my iPhone.
Google approved the app quite quickly, but when I install the update from the Play Store, no connection at all works now. I have tried uninstalling and rebooting the phone (Galaxy S22+ running Android 13 and a Galaxy S8 running Android 9) but regardless of whether I connect using mobile data or either wifi, the login sits trying forever. The app does not crash, it just won't login and although there is a timeout on the login connection, it doesn't timeout.

What could be the difference between the test version which works great, and the version I build for uploading to the Play Store?

Comment: did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your androidmanifest?

Comment: @Nguyenfamily yes that was exactly it. Added, uploaded and now working. Thanks.

Comment: cool, you can close your question now :)